# How to dynamically insert items from a Array for the filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I insert dynamically items from this array to the filter that is in wizard.html page , for when the templateUrl , which is on the route , make the call can be rendered in wizard.html page.

Controller

```
angular.module('tareasApp')
  .controller('NatureCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.pageName = $routeParams.pageName;

    $scope.items =[
     {    
          href:'/sound-waves', 
          img:'waves.jpg', 
          video:'//www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG2eGVt6v2o',
          description:'Those Relaxing Sounds of Waves'
     },
     {    
          href:'/nature-relaxing-sound', 
          img:'ocean.jpg', 
          video:'//www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWR0GdC7_40',
          description:'Nature Sounds Relaxing Ocean Sounds'
     }
    ];  
 });
```

Page wizard.html

```
<div ng-controller="NatureCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy: ['href']: ''Insert here , dynamically , the items of  array correspondent the accessed page" >

    <img ng-src="images/{{ item.img }}" width="400" height="200" >

    <p>{{item.description}}</p>

    <iframe width="655" height="400" ng-src="{{ item.video }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
</div>
</div>
```

Route

```
angular.module('tareasApp')
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

.when("/:pageName", {
     templateUrl: "views/wizard.html",
     controller: "NatureCtrl"
     })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });    
  });
```

The goal is to avoid having multiple pages with the same structure.

I use the [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) for simpler tasks , the hardest do not know how to configure. If you have any other way to do also serves the important thing is to solve this problem.

Comment: I dont think you need filter or this!

Comment: Which otherwise would have so I can solve this problem ?

Comment: After a few days doing tests I managed to fix the filter as wanted:                                                                                                           <div ng-repeat="item in grupo = (grupo|filterBy: ['href']:pageName).slice(0, 1)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the right item in the controller instead of doing so in the template.

```
$scope.item = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.href.indexOf($routeParams.pageName) === 1;
})[0];
```

And remove the `div` with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Wow! You are smart ! Worked very well. Now I'll do some tests and then return ...

Comment: The first controller operates normally , those below are being influenced and do not work . Do you know any way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean  by 'do not work'? Nothing is shown or the first page is kept shown? And what are the exact page names that you use?

Comment: In folder controllers I have 5 files js:  humor.js, main.js, promissor.js, quadrinhos.js end terra.js, the pages that are under the control of humor.js are functioning normally, both principal and articles. The main pages that are up area of ​​other controllers appear the page wizard.html, however, should appear pages main.html, promissor.html, quadrinhos.html end terra.html,  articles on these pages are functioning normally.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Problema solucionado. Era só colocar as rotas parametros abaixo das outras rotas.
Problem solved. It was only put the routes parameters beneath the other routes.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days doing tests I managed to fix the filter as wanted.

The [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) facilitates the use of filters.
Then I used the filterBy: ['href']: and added the pageName, which is the file name used na $routeParams.

```
<div ng-controller="NatureCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in grupo = (grupo|filterBy: ['href']:pageName).slice(0, 1)">

    <img ng-src="images/{{ item.img }}" width="400" height="200" >

    <p>{{item.description}}</p>

    <iframe width="655" height="400" ng-src="{{ item.video }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
</div>
</div>
```